# React-Router v4 onEnter replacement

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-thunk

I'm currently trying to build a simple react-redux app that has student and campus data in the backend. OnEnter used to work here, but it doesn't exist in the new react-router.

This app tries to load initial data at the start instead of doing a componentDidMount in each actual component. Is that the recommended approach, or are there alternative patterns that I'm not aware of?

```
/* -------------------<    COMPONENT   >------------------- */
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Students from './components/Students';

const Routes = ({ getInitialData }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} onEnter={getInitialData} />
        <Route path="/students" component={Students} />
        <Route path="*" component={Home} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

/* -------------------<   CONTAINER   >-------------------- */

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import receiveStudents from './reducers/student';
import receiveCampuses from './reducers/campus';

const mapState = null;
const mapDispatch = dispatch => ({
  getInitialData: () => {
    dispatch(receiveStudents());
    dispatch(receiveCampuses());
  }
});

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Routes);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My current solution is to put extra code in render function and not to use component property.

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {
    getInitialData();
    return <Home />;
} } />
```

Comment: The problem here is that if `getInitialData` is async, `<Home>` will render before it's done fetching. Not complaining to you, this is a fault of the v4 implementation.

Comment: In my applications I use some flag to show that data is loading and check it in the component. During loading process indicator is showing so it's not so bad for me

Answer (score 15):

I want to suggest a bit different approach. Using class inheritance you can implement your own router.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect, Route} from 'react-router';

/**
 * Class representing a route that checks if user is logged in.
 * @extends Route
 */
class AuthRequiredRoute extends Route{
  /**
   * @example <AuthRequiredRoute path="/" component={Products}>
   */
    render() {
        // call some method/function that will validate if user is logged in
        if(!loggedIn()){
            return <Redirect to="/login"></Redirect>
        }else{
          return <this.props.component />
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! But I had also to add `import React from 'react';` at the top.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: return <this.props.component /> is not valid in tsx. JSX element type 'this.props.component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Answer (score 11):

One solution is to use HOC

```
function preCondition(condition, WrappedComponent) {
   return class extends Component {
     componentWillMount() {
       condition()
     }

      render() {
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      }
    }
}

<Route exact path="/" component={preCondition(getInitialData, Home )} />
```

Comment: I really like your solution! Did you find any downside so far? Seems perfect

Comment: Can v do async calls here?

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class LoginRoute extends Component{
    render() {
        const isLogin = () => {
            if () {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        if(!isLogin()){
            return <Redirect to="/login"></Redirect>
        }else{
            return <Route path={this.props.path} exact component={this.props.component} />
        }
    }
}

export default LoginRoute;
```

Comment: @wolendranh thanks, it work for me! but this.props.history is undefined in component, so I change the code before